# Why does pyparsing's optional always return a list

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to get the LIMIT from a SQL statement

```py
query = "LIMIT 1"

LIMIT = "LIMIT"

int_num = pyparsing_common.signed_integer()

limit_clause = Optional(Group(LIMIT + int_num), None)
statement = limit_clause("limit")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = statement.parseString(query)
    print(result["limit"])
```

prints `[['LIMIT', 1]]`

This is of course a contrived example, but why does it return as `[['LIMIT', 1]]`
instead of just `1`? Is there a way to get it to just return a `1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of `pyparsing`:

- the operator `+` is an [`Expression` operator](https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HowToUsePyparsing.html#expression-operators) that "creates `And` using the expressions before and after the operator",
- the class `And` is an [`Expression` subclass](https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HowToUsePyparsing.html#expression-subclasses) that "construct with a list of ParserElements, all of which must match for And to match",
- the class `Group` is a [special subclass](https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HowToUsePyparsing.html#special-subclasses) that "causes the matched tokens to be enclosed in a list",
- the class `Optional` is an [`Expression` subclass](https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HowToUsePyparsing.html#expression-subclasses) that "construct with a ParserElement, but this element is not required to match; can be constructed with an optional `default` argument, ...".

So roughly the `+` operator creates a list of the results `'LIMIT'` and `pyparsing.pyparsing_common.signed_integer()`, and then the class `Group` creates a list containing this list. This explains why both `'LIMIT'` and `1` appear in the result, and also why they are inside nested lists.

The reality is a little more complex, because the returned objects are not `list`s, but instances of the class `pyparsing.ParseResults`. Running the following code:

```py
import pyparsing

# construct parser
LIMIT = 'LIMIT'
int_num = pyparsing.pyparsing_common.signed_integer()
limit_clause = pyparsing.Optional(pyparsing.Group(LIMIT + int_num), None)
statement = limit_clause('limit')
# parse a string
query = 'LIMIT 1'
result = statement.parseString(query)
print(repr(result))
```

prints:

```
([(['LIMIT', 1], {})], {'limit': [([(['LIMIT', 1], {})], {})]})
```

then the statement `print(repr(result['limit']))` prints:

```
([(['LIMIT', 1], {})], {})
```

and the statement `print(str(result['limit']))` prints:

```
[['LIMIT', 1]]
```

For posterity, this answer uses `pyparsing == 2.4.7` (the current development version of `pyparsing` ([GitHub repository](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing)) has been significantly restructured from a single module to a package, notably in commit [0b398062710dc00b952636bcf7b7933f74f125da](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/commit/0b398062710dc00b952636bcf7b7933f74f125da)).

A few version-related comments about the class `ParseResults`, which is used to represent each parser's result:

- in the source of `pyparsing == 2.4.7`, the class `ParserResults` is located at `pyparsing.ParserResults`: https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/pyparsing_2.4.7/pyparsing.py#L502-L1207
- the new version of the class `ParserResults` is in the module `pyparsing.results`: https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/d27fd7627f3ed60b3b7a9e9f5e790d0e49107359/pyparsing/results.py#L27-L82
- the older version of the code has been copied to the module `pyparsing_archive` in the top directory of the `pyparsing` repository, and appears to not be used (e.g., installed or imported). So the old version of the class `ParserResults` is now at: https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/d27fd7627f3ed60b3b7a9e9f5e790d0e49107359/pyparsing_archive.py#L599-L1249

Comment: Is there a way to reformulate the parser so that it returns just a `1`?

Comment: I've tried `limit_clause = Optional(Suppress(LIMIT) + int_num, None)`, which brings be closer to what I want, but it returns `[1]`

Comment: This seems to be the closest it can get to flat during parsing, because a parser combinator returns its result in a certain form, in the case of `pyparsing` as an instance of the class `pyparsing.ParseResults`, which appears to be defined at: https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/pyparsing_2.4.7/pyparsing.py#L502-L1207.

Comment: This class represents the results `list`-like and as named attributes (if named). Worth noting that `int_num.parseString('1')` is the same as the revised `limit_clause`. So this is expected to be the "flattest" it gets within the parser calls (if a parser returned something else than a `ParserResult`, then I expect that parsers built using it would not know what to do. One way to obtain the result's integer *after* parsing is complete is with `limit_clause.parseString(query).asList()[0]`. I revised my answer to add information about `pyparsing` versions and development.

Comment: Also, there are other PEG parsing frameworks too, e.g., https://github.com/erikrose/parsimonious